# C++ PictureBox gifs in Windows Form animating at near-half speed?

Tags: c++, animation, visual-studio-2015

Let me preface this question by stating that I am student who is currently learning C++ and I know near-nothing about Visual Studio. Up to this point we were using Borland C++ Builder 2010 but I made the switch to visual studio 2015 for our final mini-project for this paper.
Since this is a C++ paper, I *must* code in C++, not C# or anything else which would be a lot nicer. More importantly a lot of the problems I've been googling have produced C# solutions!
I'm much more confident with Java and C++ has been a pain so far.

Anyway, to the question:

I just got done running through a quick tutorial on how to make a quick UI application in Visual Studio which happened to feature a number generator [[link]](http://www.bogotobogo.com/cplusplus/application_visual_studio_2013.php). However, I noticed that if I were to change the image file in a picturebox to a .gif file, it'd load and display and everything but would animate about half as fast when you ran the program.
My code is (mostly) identical to that found in the link above, it's just I used my own image for the picturebox.

When I get to making my own application for my project, I planned on including a lot of animated images so I can't have them playing so slowly. Is this an inherent problem with pictureboxes and can I fix it?
I was looking into the code in both my form.h and form.cpp but I can't see hide nor hair of any update() function or anything related to timers.
I also saw something about an ImageAnimator class which apparently does animations frame-by-frame which I might look into if it'll work better than picturebox but pictureboxes are super easy for me to use.

The MyForm.h code (mostly generated by the Design view):

```
#pragma once
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>

namespace RNG {

    using namespace System;
    using namespace System::ComponentModel;
    using namespace System::Collections;
    using namespace System::Windows::Forms;
    using namespace System::Data;
    using namespace System::Drawing;

    /// <summary>
    /// Summary for MyForm
    /// </summary>
    public ref class MyForm : public System::Windows::Forms::Form
    {
    public:
        MyForm(void)
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //
            //TODO: Add the constructor code here
            //
        }

    protected:
        /// <summary>
        /// Clean up any resources being used.
        /// </summary>
        ~MyForm()
        {
            if (components)
            {
                delete components;
            }
        }
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label1;
    protected:
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label3;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label4;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label5;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label6;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Label^  label7;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button1;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::Button^  button2;
    private: System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox^  pictureBox1;

    private:
        /// <summary>
        /// Required designer variable.
        /// </summary>
        System::ComponentModel::Container ^components;

#pragma region Windows Form Designer generated code
        /// <summary>
        /// Required method for Designer support - do not modify
        /// the contents of this method with the code editor.
        /// </summary>
        void InitializeComponent(void)
        {
            System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager^  resources = (gcnew System::ComponentModel::ComponentResourceManager(MyForm::typeid));
            this->label1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label3 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label4 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label5 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label6 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->label7 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Label());
            this->button1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->button2 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::Button());
            this->pictureBox1 = (gcnew System::Windows::Forms::PictureBox());
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->BeginInit();
            this->SuspendLayout();
            // 


            //[code for 7 labels and 2 buttons, not important to question] 


            // pictureBox1
            // 
            this->pictureBox1->Image = (cli::safe_cast<System::Drawing::Image^>(resources->GetObject(L"pictureBox1.Image")));
            this->pictureBox1->Location = System::Drawing::Point(1, -2);
            this->pictureBox1->Name = L"pictureBox1";
            this->pictureBox1->Size = System::Drawing::Size(132, 104);
            this->pictureBox1->TabIndex = 9;
            this->pictureBox1->TabStop = false;
            // 
            // MyForm
            // 
            this->AutoScaleDimensions = System::Drawing::SizeF(6, 13);
            this->AutoScaleMode = System::Windows::Forms::AutoScaleMode::Font;
            this->ClientSize = System::Drawing::Size(502, 86);
            this->Controls->Add(this->pictureBox1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->button1);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label7);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label6);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label5);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label4);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label3);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label2);
            this->Controls->Add(this->label1);
            this->Name = L"MyForm";
            this->Text = L"MyForm";
            this->Load += gcnew System::EventHandler(this, &MyForm::MyForm_Load);
            (cli::safe_cast<System::ComponentModel::ISupportInitialize^>(this->pictureBox1))->EndInit();
            this->ResumeLayout(false);
            this->PerformLayout();

        }
#pragma endregion
    private: System::Void MyForm_Load(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
    }
    private: System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        int num[7] = { 0 };

        // seed
        srand((int)time(0));

        // Randomize the array values.
        for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++)
            num[i] = (rand() % 99) + 1;

        // set the label text with random number
        this->label1->Text = Convert::ToString(num[0]);
        this->label2->Text = Convert::ToString(num[1]);
        this->label3->Text = Convert::ToString(num[2]);
        this->label4->Text = Convert::ToString(num[3]);
        this->label5->Text = Convert::ToString(num[4]);
        this->label6->Text = Convert::ToString(num[5]);
        this->label7->Text = Convert::ToString(num[6]);

        // change the button states.
        //this->button1->Enabled = false;
        this->button2->Enabled = true;
    }
    private: System::Void button2_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        // clear label fields
        this->label1->Text = "0";
        this->label2->Text = "0";
        this->label3->Text = "0";
        this->label4->Text = "0";
        this->label5->Text = "0";
        this->label6->Text = "0";
        this->label7->Text = "0";

        // set button state
        this->button1->Enabled = true;
        this->button2->Enabled = false;
    }
    };
}
```

And the MyForm.cpp:

```
#include "MyForm.h"

using namespace System;
using namespace System::Windows::Forms;


[STAThread]
void Main(array<String^>^ args)
{
    Application::EnableVisualStyles();
    Application::SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

    RNG::MyForm form;
    Application::Run(%form);
}
```

It could just be that the tutorial I followed was a quick and dirty method for a GUI application and I really should be using something else. That's the feeling I'm getting the further I read into this anyway.

Comment: If your paper needs to be about C++ then this is very unlikely to keep your teacher happy.  It is not C++.  You have to call timeBeginPeriod(10) to get accurate playback speed for GIFs.

Comment: The project calls for a GUI of some description in addition to whatever code we're writing in C++. Thanks for the help though - didn't realise this wasn't really C++ stuff.